# Two jquery functions conflicting

Tags: jquery, conflict

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/f2uBW/10/)

Basically I want to include and accordion menu using jquery ui accordion and an faq section thats uses jquery to show hide the answers. The fiddle isn't a completely accurate representation but my main question is if you look at the two bits of jquery is there anything that would conflict.

Whats happening on the live site site is that the arrow icons for the faq are not showing, they show on a seperate page but aren't visable when included on the same page as the accordion.

any idea appreciated

Comment: Here is the a fiddle that works the same as the live site [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/f2uBW/15/

Comment: don't know what prevent the toggleclass open being applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is the problem.  You have the wrong image in the #faq dt.open style.  The style is being applied, you can visually see it if you use chrome developer tools or firebug.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2uBW/27/

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't the wrong image that link was a to a sprite I tried to use but doing it your way is great thank you